# Background image not displaying in IE and I don't know why

Tags: css, internet-explorer, background, header, background-image

My header background image is not displaying in IE in the #headerwrap here[Here's the site](http://mybenefits.maxxia.com.au/authoring_nl) there are reasons it's inline but they shouldn't matter.

Comment: Any particular version of Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

This was happening because the image was encoded as a .jpg but allocated a .png tag. holy hell that took some figuring out. Sometimes I've noticed on MAC in photoshop you can overwrite a .png file but save out as a .jpg and it messes everything up.